# CSLA SingleCriteria -- What's the point of the version with 2 generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, csla

There are two version of the SingleCriteria class: `SingleCriteria<B, C>` and `SingleCriteria<C>`, but it seems that the first one with two (2) type parameters is useless, at least looking at the code...

```
public class SingleCriteria<B, C> : SingleCriteria<C>
{
    public SingleCriteria(C value)
      : base(typeof (B), value) { }

    protected SingleCriteria() { }
}

public class SingleCriteria<C> : CriteriaBase<SingleCriteria<C>>
{
    private C _value;

    public C Value { get { return this._value; } }

    public SingleCriteria(C value)
    {
      this._value = value;
    }

    protected SingleCriteria() { }

    protected SingleCriteria(Type type, C value)
    {
      this._value = value;
    }

    // etc ...
}
```

---

Notice that the first one calls into the base method, but the base method doesn't actually do anything with the *type* parameter. So what was the whole point of this?

Comment: It appears to be a constructor used by the MobileFormatter(through reflection probably.) The type is probably simply there to distinguish between that constructor and the SingleCriteria(C value) above it. I'm sure it's a relic since generics came on board and just hasn't been dealt with.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the one with two generic types is older, and previously was the only one to use.  Later versions removed the need for the first type, but the existing one was left for backwards compatibility.